# Android open file manager how to show only particular file only

Tags: android

I am facing an issue while opening the File Manager from Android apps.
I want to see only particular file only which I have specific but I am able to see other file also but it is not highlight it is been grey out but how to hide that also so only particular specific file I can see no other file.

Below code which I have used:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.Action_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,"application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_REQUESTED);
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see only particular file only

Sorry, that is not an option with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: then how we can do

Comment: @AtulDhanuka: You do nothing. You let the user choose what content the user wants.